# How to compute Pairwise L1 Distance matrix on very large images in neighborhood only?

Tags: c++, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I am working on Deep learning approach for my project. And I need to calculate Distance Matrix on 4D Tensor which will be of size **N x 128 x 64 x 64 (Batch Size x Channels x Height x Width)**. The distance matrix for this type of tensor will of size **N x 128 x 4096 x 4096** and it will be impossible to fit this type of tensor in GPU, even on CPU it will require lot of memory. So, I would like to calculate the distance matrix only in some neighborhood pixels (say within radius of 5) and consider this rectangular matrix for further processing in neural network. With this approach my **distance matrix** will be of size **N x 128 x 4096 x 61**. It will take less memory in comparison to full distance matrix.

Precisely, I am trying to implement the [Convolution Random Walk Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07681.pdf). This network needs to calculate the Pairwise L1 Distance for features.

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYP3N.png)

Just to add this type of Distance Matrix is usually calculated for image segmentation via spectral clustering.

**For Example**

> ```
> X = [[a,b],[c,d]]
>
> L1_dist = [ [0, |a-b|, |a-c|, 0], 
>             [|a-b|, 0, 0, |b-d|], 
>             [|a-c|, 0, 0, |c-d| ], 
>             [0,    |b-d|, |c-d|, 0 ] 
>           ]
>
> Final_L1_dist = [ [0, |a-b|, |a-c|], // "a" is near to b and c. Including self element i.e. a 
>             [|a-b|, 0, |b-d|], // "b" is near to a and d. 
>             [|a-c|, 0, |c-d| ], // "c" is near to a and d. 
>             [|b-d|, |c-d|, 0 ] // "d" is near to b and c. 
>           ]
> ```

I would appreciate, if some one can help me to find an efficient way to compute such a matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable, example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)): a starting point for the people here that want to help you. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into figuring out how to optimize the code, without having to write one from scratch.

Comment: why your output has channel dim of 128? doesn't the L1 distance sum the abs diff along channel to get the L1 norm of `|a-b|`?

Comment: @Shai, in the architecture I am trying to implement, pairwise distance L1 is calculated per channel wise. thus output has same number of input channels.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the goal is to apply minus operation to each pixel and its surrounding neighbors. This sounds like convolution to me.

Consider the following convolution process (assume `padding='SAME'`):

[image: equation]

The 3x3 kernel calculates, for each pixel, the difference between the center pixel and its left one. For other neighbors, consider the following kernels:

[image: equation]

Thus the goal can be achieved via the following:

1. Repeat each kernel for `num_channels` times using `tf.tile`;
2. Apply each kernel channel-wisely using `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d`;
3. Do `tf.abs` to get the distance;
4. Reshape each distance tensor to `NxCx(HW)x1` and stack them properly.

For efficient `for` loop, you may consider using `tf.map_fn`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am unable to follow your approach. it would be helpful if you can explain more.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I think I misunderstood your question. May I ask why there is no `|b-c|` or `|a-d|` in your example? Is it because their distance is `sqrt(2)` instead of `1`?

Comment: Specifically, I marked them zero. I would like to find difference only between nearest pixels. In the example I am considering only Horizontal & Vertical pixels (4-Neighbours) as nearest pixels. thus I consider them as zero in final matrix.